# Codeigniter - Remove Set-Cookie param from header

Tags: codeigniter, cookies, header

I am using codegniter and for each request(url accessed) it returns 
        "Set-Cookie: _ga=GA1.2.1932062630.1531550360; ci_session=9310630596451be6ebb8de5793cec15e" .

I have tried

```
    header_remove("Set-Cookie");
```

but it doesn't work properly.

Is there any way to disable it, so that for the requests it will not be returned?

Comment: what's your CI version?

Comment: Is this happening on a local server `localhost` or deployed on a server?